# RxSwift - UITable with sections AND index

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I can see from RxSwift [examples](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/SimpleTableViewExampleSectioned/SimpleTableViewExampleSectionedViewController.swift) how to create a table with sections. How can I create a table with sections AND index numbers or alphabet, like [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/).

As there is no examples, I am guessing some extensions needs to be implemented?

Thanks